# How to Write a C program to Replace characters using command line using linux

Tags: c, file, io

I m quite new to this Systems programing i know abt the system calls but what i dont get is how to write a program to swap characters in first occurrence in a text. Hope someone can help me really struggling

Comment: You don't need system calls for that.

Comment: Pick some book from ["The Definitive C Book Guide and List"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading ...

Comment: Why does the title say "C program using command line"? Can you use C, or only bash commands or something?

Comment: Before system programming learn programming. Pick K&R and read it.

Answer (score -5):

```
void main()
{
    char a[20],b;
    char *ptr;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n Please Give The STRING OF A : ");
    scanf("%s",a);
    flushall();
    printf("\n Please Give The CHARACTER TO B : ");
    scanf("%c",&b);

ptr = strchr(a, b);

if (ptr)
   printf("The character %c is at position: %d\n", b, ptr-a+1);
else
   printf("The character was not found\n");
getch();
```

}

Comment: I dont think this is answering the OP's questions.

Comment: scanf(%s) is no good choice to teach a newbee! it has no boundary-check, so buffer-overflow is possible.

Comment: Through command line how to swap characters in a text file ive been trying some code but aint working  what i want is like from command line to enter the following ./a.out example.txt a (mycharacter) A(charactertoswap in textfile)

Comment: you all don't know anything